# Setting Snow Leopard Server for MDM (Mobile Device Management)

Tags: iphone, ios4, mdm

I just bought an enterprise account and would like on my Snow Leopard Server to enable the MDM interface for the management of my iPhone and iPad. The official documents of Apple are only sufficient. Do you know a resource guide specific to enable the server (Snow Leopard) to manage MDM? Thanks.

Comment: Because if I create a self-signed certificate is not recognized under the option MDM identity of the iPhone configuration utility? 
Learn how to create a SCEP?
What do I need an enterprise account if you do not have any documents in more than a standard account?

Comment: This is something you have to do programmatically.  There is no "on-switch" for MDM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont help if you are tied to using Snow Leopard but the latest Lion server has a simple MDM configuration server that is sufficient for most small enterprise needs. If you are trying to do something more complex then the way ahead is paved with dark well guarded secrets.

I have been told that Apple have only officially released the MDM SDK to maybe 50 companies worldwide. All of them established MDM providers.